# How to remove a field from field that is being populated mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

so

```
async findAll(req, res) {
        await WorkModel.find({})
            .sort('when')
            .populate({path: 'artists', populate: { path: 'categories'}})
            .then(response => {
                return res.status(200).json(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(500).json(error);
            });
    }
```

I need in this function remove works from the population that is happen is artists, but when I try like passing

`{path: 'artists -works', populate: { path: 'categories'}}`

I'm getting `{}` response, or even when I try

`{path: 'artists -works', populate: { path: 'categories'}}, '-works'`

in the populate

the method just get a stackTrace, I'm out of clues rn, please help me out.

Comment: You want to get only `works` field from `artists` using populate am i right ?

Comment: No, actually i was trying removing just this field from artists, now the solution is posted, thanks tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select only `works` field from `categories` collection, using populate.
you can do it using `select` !

Try this code it's help you ! For more help [mongoosejs.com](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populating-multiple-paths)

```
async findAll(req, res) {
        await WorkModel.find({})
            .sort('when')
            .populate({path: 'artists', populate: { path: 'categories', select: 'works'}})
            .then(response => {
                return res.status(200).json(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(500).json(error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: It wasn't exactly that but it helped a lot. What I was trying to do was this: 
`{path: 'artists', select:'-works', populate: { path: 'categories'}}`

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to remove the works from many-to-many relation in artists was

```
 async findAll(req, res) {
        await WorkModel.find({})
            .sort('when')
            .populate({path: 'artists', select:'-works', populate: { path: 'categories'}})
            .then(response => {
                return res.status(200).json(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(500).json(error);
            });
    }
```

Thanks for all the comments, really helped out.